# "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" but I'm using numeric variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm writing a code in R to get a plot with ggplot. In doing so, I'm running this function:

```
    BasicScatterPlotClassWrapper_b<- function(sample,pivot.var,pivot.title,lab.size,pivot.dot.size,pivot.ylab,pivot.xlab,font.size.x,font.size.y,pivot.lab,variable_y,variable_x) {
   
      sample_w <- sample %>%
      select(pivot.var) %>%
      drop_na %>%
      mutate(y.calc = variable_y)  %>%
      mutate(x.calc = variable_x)

     
    
      ## GGplot 
      gg <- ggplot(sample_w, aes(x.calc,y.calc)) +
      ggtitle(pivot.title) + 
      geom_point(aes(colour= ColoursXXX$blue)) +
      scale_color_manual(values= ColoursXXX$blue) +
      geom_text_repel(aes(x.calc,y.calc, label = ""), size = pivot.lab ,fontface = "bold") +
      xlab(pivot.xlab) +
      ylab(pivot.ylab) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
      scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
      theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9, color="black"),
            axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9, color="black"),
            axis.text.x=element_text(size = font.size.x, face = "bold",hjust= 0.5),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size = font.size.y, face = "bold",hjust= 0.5),
            legend.position="none", 
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
            axis.line = element_line(size = 0.2, colour = "black"))

      return(gg)
      
      
    }
```

If I substitute the inputs from the function with their actual value, I can get the plot. If I call the function with a specific command to export the plot in PPT, I get this error: "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

The inputs are the following ones:

```
openChartPPT(BasicScatterPlotClassWrapper_b(
                                           sample=DF, 
                                           pivot.var= c("COV.proj.ratio", "COV.curr.ratio"),
                                           pivot.title="",
                                           lab.size=3,
                                           pivot.dot.size=2,
                                           pivot.ylab="bla bla",
                                           pivot.xlab="bla bla bla", 
                                           font.size.x=7, 
                                           font.size.y=7,
                                           pivot.lab=2,
                                           variable_y = "COV.proj.ratio",
                                           variable_x = "COV.curr.ratio"), width = 8, height = 6)
```

The two variables COV.proj.ratio and COV.curr.ratio are numeric.

Do you have any clue about what the issue could be?

Many thanks,
R

Comment: You pass the variables as strings to your function, e.g. `mutate(y.calc = variable_y)` assigns the string "COV.proj.ratio" to `y.calc`. Hence it's discrete. You have to convert the strings to symbols. Try `mutate(y.calc = !!sym(variable_y)` and the same for x.calc.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not working. Also because when I paste COV.proj.ratio in it it works smoothly. Indeed it takes it from the data frame 'sample' as ```%>%``` connects the lines

Comment: Yep. When you do `mutate(y.calc = COV.proj.ratio)` it will work but you are doing `mutate(y.calc = "COV.proj.ratio")`.

Comment: Oh well, it's actually working, I made a mistake in the code! Thanks a lot Stefan, you've been super helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the variables as strings to your function, e.g. `mutate(y.calc = variable_y)` assigns the string `"COV.proj.ratio"` to `y.calc`. Hence it's discrete.

You have to convert the strings to symbols via `!!sym()`.

Using some random sample data try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF <- data.frame(COV.proj.ratio = runif(100), COV.curr.ratio = runif(100))

BasicScatterPlotClassWrapper_b <- function(sample,pivot.var,pivot.title,lab.size,pivot.dot.size,pivot.ylab,pivot.xlab,font.size.x,font.size.y,pivot.lab,variable_y, variable_x) {
  
  sample_w <- sample %>%
    select(pivot.var) %>%
    drop_na %>%
    mutate(y.calc = !!sym(variable_y))  %>%
    mutate(x.calc = !!sym(variable_x))
  
  ## GGplot 
  gg <- ggplot(sample_w, aes(x.calc,y.calc)) +
    ggtitle(pivot.title) + 
    geom_point(colour = "blue") +
    #scale_color_manual(values= "blue") +
    ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(x.calc,y.calc, label = ""), size = pivot.lab ,fontface = "bold") +
    xlab(pivot.xlab) +
    ylab(pivot.ylab) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9, color="black"),
          axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9, color="black"),
          axis.text.x=element_text(size = font.size.x, face = "bold",hjust= 0.5),
          axis.text.y=element_text(size = font.size.y, face = "bold",hjust= 0.5),
          legend.position="none", 
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
          axis.line = element_line(size = 0.2, colour = "black"))
  
  return(gg)
  
  
}

BasicScatterPlotClassWrapper_b(
  sample=DF, 
  pivot.var= c("COV.proj.ratio", "COV.curr.ratio"),
  pivot.title="",
  lab.size=3,
  pivot.dot.size=2,
  pivot.ylab="bla bla",
  pivot.xlab="bla bla bla", 
  font.size.x=7, 
  font.size.y=7,
  pivot.lab=2,
  variable_y = "COV.proj.ratio",
  variable_x = "COV.curr.ratio")
```

[image]